Windows Notepad replace paragraph break with a character
I'm using a batch file to collect file names inside a folder:
dir /a /b /-p /o:gen >names.txt

The result is a txt file with file names but has paragraph breaks:
file1.psd
file2.psd
file3.psd

I need to replace the paragraph breaks with a comma so it should be:
file1.psd,file2.psd,file3.psd

Tried \n and ^p but it doesn't work. It works on Word and Notepad++ but if possible, I prefer it be done in notepad (if there's a way). Is there?

Which version of windows (and therefore notepad) are you on?

But if it's just about removing empty lines (which is what I understand you mean with "paragraph" breaks) you probably can include that in your script instead of manually doing it with notepad. See this https://superuser.com/a/1513226

It is not possible using Notepad.exe, because that editor does not support finding end of line.
But, when you create a batchfile like this:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET s=
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f IN (names.txt) DO SET s=!s!,%%f
ECHO %s:~1%

The output should look like:
file1.psd,file2.psd,file3.psd

The "tokens=*" will take care of filenames containing a space.

If you want to replace paragraph breaks (newlines) with a comma in Notepad++, follow these steps:

Open the file in Notepad++.

Press Ctrl + H to open the "Find and Replace" dialog.

In the Find what field, enter \r\n (for Windows) or \n (for other systems).

In the Replace with field, type..

Select Match using Regular Expression at the bottom.

Click Replace All.



OP clearly state, they are able to do it in notepad++ but prefer the builtin windows notepad

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
